# main or header file which will compiler execute first?

Tags: c, compiler-construction, header-files

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{    
    printf("hi");    
}
```

which will be executed first main or header file?

does main program will execute first and include the contents of header file?

Comment: The compiler doesn't execute anything. It only compiles source code. And it compiles it in the order the statements, declarations etc. are present.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`#include` means textual insertion of the file at exactly the line where the `#include` is found. That is done by the preprocessor, so the compiler doesn't see the `#include` command itself anymore. In your case that means that first all code from stdio.h is *compiled* and then your function `main()`. But nevertheless program *execution* always starts with `main()`

Answer (score 3):

C compiles translation units. A translation unit is built up as if the included files existed in the main source file at the point where you include them.

So, in this case, the compiler *sees* the contents of the header file before it sees `main` (it doesn't actually *execute* any of them).

Section `6.10.2 Source file inclusion /2` of C11 is the controlling section (same section number in C99) of the ISO standard:

> A preprocessing directive of the form
>
> **`# include <h-char-sequence> new-line`**
>
> searches a sequence of implementation-defined places for a header identified uniquely by the specified sequence between the `<` and `>` delimiters, and causes the replacement of that directive by the entire contents of the header. How the places are specified or the header identified is implementation-defined.

As to what gets executed first when you run your program, there are various initialisation actions outside your direct control but the first execution of C *code* begins with `main`, at least for a hosted environment. In free-standing environments such as embedded systems or operating systems llike Linux, the standard allows for any starting point.

Answer (score 2):

Simply said, `#include` does nothing more than paste the contents of the included file.  So things are compiled in the order you `#include` files, and place code.

Answer (score 0):

The translation of  a  C program is done in 8 phases. In phase 4 include directives are executed and in phase 8 output from phase 7 is collected to form an executable.